# Help with duality and recursive definitions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm struggling with the following problem:

> Let $L_1^*$  be the language obtained from $L_1$  by removing $\to$
>   and $\leftrightarrow$ from the stock of connectives (leaving it with
>   $\neg, ∧, ∨, \top,$ and $\bot$). And let $\phi^*$ be the formula
>   obtained from a formula $\phi$ of $L_1^*$ by replacing any occurrence
>   of $∧$ by $∨$, any occurrence of $∨$ by $∧$, any occurrence of $\bot$
>   by $\top$, and any occurrence of $\top$ by $\bot$.
>
> $(a)$Give a recursive definition of $\phi^*$ — i.e. of the function
>   $\phi \mapsto \phi^*$.
>
> $(b)$ Given a structure $A$, define $A^∗$ by stipulating that $A^∗(P) = f_{\neg}(A(P))$ — in other words, $A^∗(P) = \top(\bot)$ if and only if $A(P) = \bot(\top)$. Show, by induction on the complexity of formulae, that, for any $\phi$ and any $A$, $|\phi^∗|_A = f_{\neg}(|\phi|_{A^∗} )$ — in other words, $|\phi^∗|_A = \top(\bot)$
>   if and only if $|\phi|_{A^∗} = \bot(\bot)$.
>
> $(c)$ Deduce that $\phi \models \psi$ if and only if $\psi^∗ \models \phi^∗$, and that $\phi$ is tautologous if and only if $\phi^∗$ is
>   unsatisfiable.

**Looks like (a) is solved:**

1) $P^* = P$, for any atomic formulae $P$

$[$1b) $\top^* = \bot$

1c) $\bot^* = \top]$

2a) $(\phi ∧ \psi)^* = (\phi^* ∨ \psi^*)$

2b) $(\phi ∨ \psi)^* = (\phi^* ∧ \psi^*)$

**My attempt at (b):**

I assume that the directions to "define $A^*$" mean to provide a recursive definition. I am guessing this would look similar to part (a), so that:

1) $|\phi^*|_A = f_{\neg}(|\neg\phi|_{A^*})$, for any sentence $\phi$

$[$1b) $|\top|_A = |\bot|_{A^*}$

1c) $|\bot|_A = |\top|_{A^*}]$

2a) $|(\phi ∧ \psi)^*|_A = f_{∨}(|(\neg\phi ∨ \neg\psi)|_{A^*})$

2b) $|(\phi ∨ \psi)^*|_A = f_{∧}(|(\neg\phi ∧ \neg\psi)|_{A^*})$

**My attempt at (c):**

(i) $\phi \models \psi$

By contraposition: $\neg\psi \models \neg\phi$

(ii) By the definition of $A^*$, which stipulates $A^*(P) = f_{\neg}(A(P))$:

$|\neg\phi|_A = f_{\neg}(|\phi^*|_{A^*})$

$|\neg\psi|_A = f_{\neg}(|\psi^*|_{A^*})$

(iii) Thus, if $\phi \models \psi$ (under $A$), then under $A^*$: $\psi^*\models\phi*$

Comment: You are, as you suspected, overcomplicating part (a). One clause in the desired definition of the * operation should be $(\phi_1\land\phi_2)^*=(\phi_1^*)\lor(\phi_2^*)$. The other clauses are similar to this.

Comment: Wow, I overthought it entirely... I've updated my attempt in my answer. Look better?

Comment: Wow... Why would anyone down vote this?

Comment: Regarding your new 2a). Where in the rules does it say that, for instance, $\neg p$ should become $p$?

Comment: @GitGud Thanks for the support. I thought the downvoting was odd too. You are right, negation is not flipped. I just got caught up in reversing connectives!

Comment: For the new attempt. Just say $P^*=P$ for any atomic $P$. Otherwise good.

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you. I've also added an attempt at (b).

Comment: Added (c) as well.